# pyocd library cannot find libusb python library

Tags: python, debugging, usb, libusb, gdbserver

I've successfully installed pyocd and libusb using powershell core and python 3.8 on windows 10, but when I use `python -m pyocd list` command, it throws this error:

```
PS C:\Users\mahya> python -m pyocd list
0003915:WARNING:common:STLink and CMSIS-DAPv2 probes are not supported because no libusb library was found.
No available debug probes are connected
```

this is the list of installed python libraries:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should copy the [libusb.dll](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases/download/v1.0.23/libusb-1.0.23.7z) (libusb dynamic link library) to the path of python instalation.
Note: if you've downloaded python from windows store, you should copy `libusb.dll` in `C:/windows/system32` directory.